# I am unable to transfer values between samplers using JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables() in jmeter java

Tags: java, jmeter

I am relatively new to Jmeter so please bearvwith me :) According to the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterVariables--), ***getJMeterVariables*** returns the jmeter variables for the current thread which I believed was instantiated when I created the ***JavaSamplerContext***. However, it seems like its not the case as ***JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables*** is null and when I try to add values to it:

```
 JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables().put("something","something");
```

I get null pointer exception. My goal is to debug how values pass between samplers and my scenario is something like the following - a main class that calls the different samplers and looks like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sampler1 sampler1 = new Sampler1();
        Sampler2 sampler2 = new Sampler2();
        JavaSamplerContext context = new JavaSamplerContext(getArguments());

        Sampler1.runTest(context);
        Sampler2.runTest(context);

}
```

I would like to use JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables().put("something","something") to transfer values between sampler1 and sampler2 and hence Sampler1 for example looks like:

```
public class Sampler1 extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {


    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

    SampleResult result = new SampleResult();

    result.sampleStart();
    Something1 something1 = doSomething();
    String something2 = doSomething2()
    result.sampleEnd();

    context.getJMeterVariables().putObject("something1Key",Something1);
    context.getJMeterVariables().put("something2Key",something2);
    return result;
}
```

While sampler2 will have: (**Note that I am trying to transfer both String and an Object**)

```
public class Sampler2 extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

String something2 = context.getJMeterVariables().get("something2Key");
Something1 something1 = (Something1) context.getJMeterVariables().getObject("something1Key");
...
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run the code like you do, if you look at [getJMeterVariables()  function source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.java#L243) you will see that it calls [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class which is null because I fail to see where you start JMeter in your code.

You may want to take a look at [SleepTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/150a2753b4bb055c678965a1ec9a66af3362345d/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java) or [JavaTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/150a2753b4bb055c678965a1ec9a66af3362345d/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java) example implementations which are being used in [Java Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) to get the overall idea of using AbstractJavaSamplerClient, but again if you try to run them directly - you get an error because JMeter Context will not be initialized.

So compile your classes into .jar file, drop it under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and run JMeter - the variables should be set/transferred across samplers.

If you want to run JMeter from Java code - take a look at [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article